# Excel related query for the merging of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

In my worksheet, there are several names in column A in which many of them are identical. I want to merge all identical names along with the numerical data present in their respective column B. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "i want to merge all the same name along with the numerical data present in there respective column B". Please elaborate and give an example to understand your question clearly

Answer (score 2):

Create a pivot table from the data. Put the names in the rows and sum the values in column B.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table will work especially if you want a unique list of names. You may also try a sumifs() function in column C. This is assuming your numerical data is in column B.

in C1 put sumifs(A:A,B:B,A1)

if your data starts in A2 put the formula in C2 and replace A1 with A2 ect.

Copy this formula down the list and each entry will have the total of the numerical data for each name in column C.